# How to get data from one api call to another using deferred object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-grid, jquery-deferred

I have to make two api calls - tenants and users. The tenant api returns all the existing tenants details and the user api will return all the users in a particular tenant. I need to map the tenant ids with their details after the first function call. I have to use these key values as a parameter to the second api call (which takes the tenant ids (integer)). After the second api call finishes, I have to create another map for users with the tenant ids as key and the user details as value.

```
    var tenants = {};
    var users = {};
    function func1() {
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: crudUrl("tenants"),
                        success: function (response) {
                            response.forEach(function (item) {
                                var TTId = item.Id.toString();
                                if (!("key" in tenants)) {
                                    tenants[TTId] = item;
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }

    function func2(key) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: crudUrl("tenants/{tenantId}/users"),
                        data: {
                            tenantId: key
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            var detail = [];
                            var TTId = key;
                            response.forEach(function (item) {
                                var uid = {}
                                uid.Id = item.Id;
                                uid.Name = item.Name;
                                detail.push(uid);
                            })
                            users[TTId] = detail;
                        }
                    });
                }

       $.when(func1()).then(function () {
            for (var key of Object.keys(tenants)) {
                func2(parseInt(key));
            }
        });
```

The above method works but the network becomes too loaded since it has to make multiple ajax calls in func2 for each of the keys obtained from func1. I'm pretty sure this can be done using deferred object also, but I can't figure out how to go with it. I'm new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you change the API at all?  This seems a particularly inefficient method to load all the data.  Do you even need to load *all* the data in one go?  Normally it's done like this so you load the tenant list then, when the user selects a tenant, you load the user list just for that one tenant, rather than load everything up-front.

Comment: Actually I have to use these two maps, so that I can change the row template's data of a kendo grid.

Comment: Does that stop you adding another API call that loads all the data in one go?  You don't mention the server-side tech, so you could probably also load it all up-front in the initial render.  I never mentioned changing the maps, just how it's populated.  Seems you have an XY problem.